# Objective-c : Convert JSON array of dictionaries to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

So, I have the following structure in JSON, which I understand to be an array of key/value pair objects:

```
{
"notification": [
    {
        "uid": "20",
        "count": "4"
    },
    {
        "uid": "48",
        "count": "0"
    },
    {
        "uid": "49",
        "count": "0"
    },
    {
        "uid": "53",
        "count": "0"
    }
]
}
```

Parsing this with SBJson will result in a collection of dictionaries with one key/value pair each.

I would like to "implode" all of these dictionaries into one dictionary with many key/value pairs. Not worrying about duplicates by the way.

Whats the best way to go about doing this? How can I iterate through a NSDictionary, accessing each item one at a time and pulling out both it's key and value?

Any ideas on this?

Thanks.

--Conor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply iterate through the already existing array of `NSDictionary`s. That's the convenience of JSON, you easily get usable data structures out of your feed string.

```
NSArray *notifications = [[theFeedString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"notification"];  
// or whatever JSON helper you are using
for (NSDictionray *dict in notifications) {
   NSInteger uid = [[dict objectForKey:@"uid"] intValue];
   NSInteger count = [[dict objectForKey:@"count"] intValue];
   // do something with uid and count
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. pretty obvious and simple but in my defense, it was friday :D

Answer (score 0):

1. Create custom class Notification with properties `uid` and `count`.
2. To iterate through NSDictionary/NSArray use `for` statement. Create
   and init your Notification object with parsed data from `json` on each
   iteration
3. Add that object to new array or dictionary (for dictionary you can create
   a key which would be the same as `uid`, for example)